# NoMethodError undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

I know this kind of question is already answered multiple times but i seriously unable to figure it out what is causing a problem here, I am having trouble solving this problem. I keep getting the same error when i'm trying to create new registration ( http://localhost:3000/registrations/new?course_id=1 ) :

```
NoMethodError at /registrations

undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

Here is my RegistrationsController:

```
class RegistrationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_registration, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @registrations = Registration.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @registration = Registration.new
    @course = Course.new
    @course = Course.find_by id: params["course_id"]
  end

  def create
    @registration = Registration.new registration_params.merge(email: stripe_params["stripeEmail"], card_token: stripe_params["stripeToken"])
    raise "Please Check Registration Errors" unless @registration.valid?
    @registration.process_payment
    @registration.save
    redirect_to @registration, notice: 'Registration was successfully created.'
  rescue Exception => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    render :new
  end

  protect_from_forgery except: :webhook
  def webhook
    event = Stripe::Event.retrieve(params["id"])

    case event.type
      when "invoice.payment_succeeded" #renew subscription
        Registration.find_by_customer_id(event.data.object.customer).renew
    end
    render status: :ok, json: "success"
  end

  private

    def stripe_params
      params.permit :stripeEmail, :stripeToken
    end

    def set_registration
      @registration = Registration.find(params[:id])
    end

    def registration_params
      params.require(:registration).permit(:course_id, :full_name, :company, :telephone, :email, :card_token)
    end

end
```

My Registration Model:

```
class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course

  def process_payment
    customer_data = {email: email, card: card_token}.merge((course.plan.blank?)? {}: {plan: course.plan})
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create customer_data

      Stripe::Charge.create customer: customer.id,
                            amount: course.price * 100,
                            description: course.name,
                            currency: 'usd'
      #Annotate Customer Id when Registration is Created
      cusotmer_id = customer.id

  end

  def renew
    update_attibute :end_date, Date.today + 1.month
  end

end
```

Registration New.html.haml File :

```
%section#course-content
  %section#ruby
    %section.detailed-syllabus
      .wrapper-inside
        = form_for @registration, html: { class: "basic-grey" } do |f|
          - if @registration.errors.any?
            #error_explanation
              %h2
                = pluralize(@registration.errors.count, "error")
                prohibited this registration from being saved:
              %ul
                - @registration.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
                  %li= message
          .field
            = f.hidden_field :course_id, value: @course.id
          .field
            = f.label :full_name
            = f.text_field :full_name
          .field
            = f.label :company
            = f.text_field :company
          .field
            = f.label :email
            = f.text_field :email
          .field
            = f.label :telephone
            = f.text_field :telephone

            //‘Stripe.js’ will recognize the card data because we have marked the inputs with ‘data-stripe’ attribute as: number, cvv, exp-month and exp-year.
            = javascript_include_tag "https://js.stripe.com/v2/"
            :javascript
              Stripe.setPublishableKey('#{Rails.application.secrets.stripe_publishable_key}');

            = label_tag "Card Number", nil, required: true
            .control-group
              .controls
                = text_field_tag :card_number, nil, class: "input-block-level", "data-stripe" => "number"

            = label_tag "Card Verification", nil, required: true
            .control-group
              .controls
                = text_field_tag :card_verification, nil, class: "input-block-level", "data-stripe" => "cvv"

            = label_tag "Card Expires", nil, required: true
            = select_tag :exp_month, options_for_select(Date::MONTHNAMES.compact.each_with_index.map { |name,i| ["#{i+1} - #{name}", i+1] }), include_blank: false, "data-stripe" => "exp-month", class: "span2"
            = select_tag :exp_year, options_for_select((Date.today.year..(Date.today.year+10)).to_a), include_blank: false, "data-stripe" => "exp-year", class: "span1"


          .actions
          = f.submit "Registration Payment", class: "btn", style: "color: white;background: rgb(242, 118, 73);"
```

Does anyone know how to assist me in this? Greatly appreciate all the help.
Additional Can anyone please guide me through how to pass id between 2 models like this guy did between 2 models as he's creating a scaffold for one model but passing ID lets him create values for another model too without creating actions for another controller https://github.com/gotealeaf/stripe-basics.git

Edited:
GitHub Repository For This Code
https://github.com/ChiragArya/Stripe_CheckOut_Demo

Comment: On which line in this error happening?

Comment: block in _app_views_registrations_new_html_haml Here :
= f.hidden_field :course_id, value: @course.id

Comment: `@course` is **nil**.

Comment: you are finding @course against a param["course_id"] which obviously does not exist, first create a course in your db against given ID and than try to do registration.

Comment: I already has multiple Course through seeds
 Course.create name: "INTRODUCTION TO REPOSTERY (4 Weeks)", price: 475

Comment: How are you redirected to `new.html.erb` page? If by clicking a link, then post that code.

Comment: Should i upload the code to github and then show you ?

Comment: Please update it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, it appears the error is caused by :

> `@course.id` being `nil`

The way to fix this is to ensure `@course` is defined properly. You need to do the following:

```
def new
   @registration = Registration.new
   @course = Course.find_by id: params["course_id"]
end
```

The other issue you have here is that your routes should be able to handle `courses` without having to append them with `?course_id=1`:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :registrations do
   get :course_id, to: "registrations#new" #-> yoururl.com/registrations/:course_id
end
```

This will still give you the `course_id` param in the `new` action; just makes it more Rails.

--

**Controller**

You also need some structure in your code (you're aiming for [fat model, thin controller](http://www.slideshare.net/damiansromek/thin-controllers-fat-models-proper-code-structure-for-mvc)). It looks like you're coming to Rails as a Ruby dev; you need to appreciate that Rails handles most of the exceptions etc for you.

Specifically, you need to look at how to remove code out of your actions:

```
 def create
    @registration = Registration.new registration_params
    @registration.process_payment
    if @registration.save
        redirect_to @registration, notice: 'Registration was successfully created.'
    else
        # handle error here
    end
  end

  private

  def registration_params
      params.require(:registration).permit(:course_id, :full_name, :company, :telephone, :email, :card_token).merge(email: stripe_params["stripeEmail"], card_token: stripe_params["stripeToken"])
  end
```

-

> `id' for nil:NilClass

Finally, you have to remember this error basically means the variable you're trying to invoke an action for is `nil`.

Ruby populates `nil` variables with a `NilClass` object, thus it's difficult to determine what the error actually is. All it means is that the variable you're trying to call a method on *doesn't* have the aforementioned method, as Ruby has populated it with the `NilClass` object.

Comment: Thanks Sir for your reply(+1), i quite understand a lot but this actually brings me to another error(This time Stripe)
This customer has no attached payment source

Comment: Okay, thanks for the comment. For now, comment out the stripe stuff and see if your original error is fixed. If it is, you should close this question and open a new one for the Stripe issue

Comment: Yup already checked that, issue is fixed now. Sir can you please answer my second question too about passing ID if any guide or tutorial for that ?
Again thanks for your great answer Accepting this.

Comment: Where is your second question, have you got a link?

Comment: It's in this question only down below 
Additional Can anyone please guide me through how to pass id between 2 models like this guy did between 2 models as he's creating a scaffold for one model but passing ID lets him create values for another model too without creating actions for another controller https://github.com/gotealeaf/stripe-basics.git
I did understand from your answer but can you guide me through this in more detail please

Comment: You'll probably need to look up `foreign_key`s in Rails, and form an association between the two models.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing Registration#new action to

```
def new

  @course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
  @registration = @course.registrations.new

end
```

Comment: well after doing this it gives me error 
undefined method `registrations' for nil:NilClass this won't even let the registration form pop out

Comment: I don't think i.e necessary as i'm not creating courses separately.

Comment: i tried with both but no success as when i put your code it don't even let me fill out the form it gives straight error when hitting on register.

Answer (score 0):

add this in your `def create`

```
def create
    @course = Course.find_by id: params["registration"]["course_id"]
    @registration = Registration.new registration_params.merge(email: stripe_params["stripeEmail"], card_token: stripe_params["stripeToken"])
    raise "Please Check Registration Errors" unless @registration.valid?
    @registration.process_payment
    @registration.save
    redirect_to @registration, notice: 'Registration was successfully created.'
  rescue Exception => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    @course = Course.find_by id: params["registration"]["course_id"]
    render :new
end
```

Comment: well after this when i create new registration then instead of taking me to show page it redirects me to index page with the form(new.html.haml)
i edited my question with  github repo if you can take a look at please.